# Array values in TeamCity configuration parameter

Tags: arrays, teamcity

I have build step 1, which generate multiple path (http://dir1, http://dir2, etc) and make some variable in powershell $checkout. The type of this variable is array. In the same build step 1 i push this variable to configuration parameter in TeamCity

```
Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='CHECKOUT_URL' value='$checkout']"
```

Next build step contains FOREACH cycle. The idea of it is to make build step 2 execute some (algorithm) for each element in array $checkout.

Problem is:
when build step 1 is finished, $checkout is array
when build step 2 trying to execute himself, $checkout is string

I tried to transform $checkout in build step 2 into array, but didnt succeed. Is there is a way to keep $checkout in parameter like an array and use it like array in different build steps?

Comment: try to format array as json string, and then parse json into array...

Comment: Seems like TC doesnt get json. If i
$checkout | convertto-json

and then 

Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='CHECKOUT_URL' value='$checkout']"

the result TC log is

##teamcity[setParameter name='CHECKOUT_URL' value='[
[11:50:05] [Step 2/12]     "http://dir
[11:50:05] [Step 2/12]     "http://dir1
[11:50:05] [Step 2/12]     "http://dir2
....
[11:50:05] [Step 2/12]     "http://dirN"
[11:50:05] [Step 2/12] ]']

build step doesnt get the parametr. In next build step 2 this parameter is NULL, because somehow TC push value of variable $checkout in "set parameter code"

Comment: probably `convertto-json` converts array to multi-line string. try `-Compress` parameter to omit any formatting spaces

Comment: Another problem achived) after `-compress` option TC miss the last quotes. My code is `Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='CHECKOUT_URL' value='$checkout']"`, but in build log TC miss last characters `<']>`. Because of that parameter didnt stored

Comment: right, square brackets have to be escaped... https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-Escapedvalues

Comment: Since URLs cannot contain spaces or special characters like square brackets, a space-separated list would be simpler. The JSON with `|`-escaping is still useful in the more generic case.